# How do I survive my first night?

Tags: five-nights-at-freddys

I'm on my first night at Freddy's, and I can't seem to get past the first night. The issue is if I keep the camera on room 1A then [the monsters/bots don't seem to do anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SDp3.jpg), and my Power keeps going down, but the time doesn't seem to go by.

Once they start to move they gradually get closer to the Security Room, and then I'm forced to lock the door. Typically I can survive until 4AM, or 5Am, but usually my Power will run out then I die.

So, how can I survive the first night at Freddy's?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need to use the camera at all on your first night. simply flash the lights on your doorways periodically and close them when you have "visitors". You can also flash the lights with the door closed to see if they are still behind the door.

You can periodically check 1A to see who is out and about, but usually just the bunny is active for most of the night with the bird coming later (around 3-4).

theres a chance (slight) that Freddy(the bear) himself will start wandering around at 5am. keep an eye on 2B and 4B because that his where he likes to hang out.

From the second night on you really need to only watch 1C (pirates cove) as the "thing" in there behaves similar to Slenderman (moves around when you aren't watching).

Markiplier ( a famous youtuber) uses this same strategy to beat the game

Answer (score 4):

### The Science behind the Animatronics

Getting to know the animatronics is an important step of learning the game.

Bonnie is the first animatronic. Bonnie is the purple rabbit and will always appear on the left door. You can see when Bonnie is at your door and ready to attack by turning on the left light or by checking Camera 2B.

Chica is the next animatronic. Chica is the duck and will always appear on the right door. Just like Bonnie you can see when Chica is ready to attack by turning on your right door light or by checking camera 4B.

Foxy is the third animatronic. Foxy is by himself in Pirate Cove on camera 1C. Foxy will slowly peak out of his curtain and rush your left door if he comes all the way out, he will attack after 25 seconds or after 3 seconds if you check cam 2A. If your door is down during this attack he will take some of your power, on the first attack he takes 1%, on the second attack he will take 6%, and on any other attacks he will take 11%. The only way to stop Foxy is to use the camera, while on any camera Foxy will stop peeking out and freeze.

Freddy is the 4th animatronic and he always comes on the right door, it is pretty unlikely for Freddy to ever make it to your door and attack. Even on Night 6 Freddy's AI level is set to 4, I'll go into more about what that means later. If Freddy does make it to your door you won't be able to see him using your lights, you have to check camera 4B to see if he's there. Unlike the other Animatronics Freddy doesn't really leave, he will go down the hall but can come back just a few seconds after he leaves.

Golden Freddy is the final animatronic and it is very rare for you to ever see him. When checking camera 2B there is a 0.00001% chance for the poster to be replaced with a Golden Freddy poster. After putting down your monitor you will see Golden Freddy sitting in your office even if you had your doors closed. You have 5 seconds to put up your monitor before he attacks, killing you and crashing the game.

**Now that we've gone over all the animatronics let's go into their Movement.**

How often the animatronics move depends on their AI level, the image below shows the animatronics AI level depending on the night

[image: AI levels]

It should also be noted that these do increase through out the night. At 2 am Bonnie goes up 1 AI level, and 3 am Bonnie, Chica and Foxy go up one AI level, and at 4 AM Bonnie, Chica, and Foxy go up one more AI level.

Every 4-5 seconds the animatronics are given a chance to move. A random number between 1 and 20 is chosen and if that number is less than or equal to the animatronics current AI level they are allowed to move or attack if they are by an open door. Foxy's movement is him peaking around his curtain and he won't move if you are on or were recently on a camera.

### A good strategy

Using the info we know about the animatronics we can come up with a good strategy.

A very good strategy is to really only use your lights, only checking your camera to stop Foxy and see if Freddy is outside your door. Check each light very quickly before going on your camera, this will make sure that Bonnie and Chica can't attack you for at least 8 seconds. After you check your lights go onto your cameras, check on Foxy to make sure that he's not about to attack then check on Freddy to see if he's outside your door.

Once you see Freddy at your door things get tricky, like I said before he doesn't really leave that door so you can stop checking camera 4B. What I have found works best is putting your right door down when you check cams but keeping it up while you check lights. He still does have a chance of getting in but on the later nights you don't really have the power to always have the door down.

With this strategy you should be able to get through the 6 nights pretty easily and have a chance at beating 20-20-20-20 mode

**A few things I didn't mention**

As the nights go on your base power consumption slowly goes up. Night 2 takes 1% every 6 seconds, Night 3 takes 1% every 5 seconds, Night 4 takes 1% every 4 seconds, and Nights 5, 6, and 7 take 1% every 3 seconds.

If you are on your camera when Chica or Bonnie attack they will wait up to 20-30 seconds before pulling down the monitor and attacking you. If you close the monitor you will immediately die. Freddy can also enter your room while you are on your monitor but he won't attack until you pull it down.

When the power goes out all animatronics stop moving, even if an animatronic was waiting for you to put down your camera they won't kill you. You can't do anything except hope you reach 6am before Freddy comes for you. Every 5 seconds you have a 20% chance for Freddy to show up and start playing music up to a maximum of 20 seconds, after Freddy shows up there is a 20% chance every 5 seconds up to a maximum of 20 seconds for a complete blackout, after this there is a 20% chance every 2 seconds for you to die.

I think I covered everything but feel free to ask about anything I missed.

Answer (score 3):

Don't rely too heavily on the camera, just check periodically (and quickly) the five cameras around your room and Pirate's Cove. Check the lights around your doors on occasion and only shut the doors when they're visible from your doorways. When you've shut the door on one of them, check for them with your light, you can tell the difference if they're outside the door or not. Open the door when they're no longer there.

Answer (score 1):

Chicca and bonnie are most likley to kill you when in the first night. (i had to find this out the hard way). So keep flashing the light and rarley check the camera.
The anamatronics usally start moving around 2am.goodluck!

Answer (score 1):

I've beat the game many time's and on the 1'st night stay calm,Bonnie is most active around 3:am-6:am and don't keep your door closed,many people say it work's but it does not,I've tried it and it doesn't work. Close your door only when you need to.